# Generating a JAR Manifest

Tags: java

I need to generate a manifest for a jar file (In code) containing the following permissions:

```
Permissions: all-permissions
```

So far I've gotten this far:

```
    Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
    Attributes global = manifest.getMainAttributes();
    global.put(new Attributes.Name("Permissions"), "all-permissions");
    File jarLoader = new File("test.jar");
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(jarLoader);
    JarOutputStream jos = new JarOutputStream(os, manifest);
    jos.close();
```

However this completely erases the contents of the jar file, creates the manifest, and the manifest is blank. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong after reading some information on this and would like someone to point me in the correct direction.

Comment: Do you want do merge the manifest into an existing jar file? Currently you are generating a manifest and save it into a fresh and empty jar file.

Comment: @Matthias - This is correct. The jar file is already present.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding (i'm no expert) you should open a JarInputStream for the jar file that you already have and iterate over the JarEntry's (like here: [jarinputstreamexample](http://www.concretepage.com/java/example-of-jarinputstream-in-java)). Every entry that does not belong to "Manifest.mf" you pass directly to the next JarOutputStream (you have one of those already available, right?). For the JarEntry belonging to the current jar's manifest.mf you replace by your own version and you are done!

Sorry for not beeing more specific.